# Having this error in the console Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

The problem I am facing is kind of strange, I am iterating the data, I can see displaying all of the props, in the first item of the array, but the rest of the items it's displaying all the props except (book.Nareted, book.length), I am having the error in the console  `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` that might me a problem  here is the API that I am taking data from https://json-api-smaiil.herokuapp.com/books

```
import React from 'react'
import HoverBooks from './HoverBooks';
import { useHistory, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Books = ({category}) => {
    return (     
        <div className='books__main'>      
        {category.slice(0, 5).map((book) => {       
          return(
            <>
           <HoverBooks 
           key={book.id}
           {...book}       
           />    
           <div className='book__content'>
            <li key={book.id}>{book.bookName}</li>
             <h4>By{book.by}</h4>
             <h4>Narreted by:{book.Narreted}</h4>
             <h4>Length: {book.length}</h4>
             <h4>Release Date: {book.ReleaseDate}</h4>
             <h4>Language: {book.Language}</h4>
             <h4>{book.rating}</h4>
           </div>           
            </>
        )})}

 </div>
    )
}
export default Books
```

Comment: Put the key on your fragment as that's the wrapping item.

Comment: Yes; use `<React.Fragment key={book.id}>...</Fragment>` instead of `<>...</>`, also remove the `key={...}` from the child items.

Answer (score 2):

```
     <h4>Narreted by:{book.Narreted || book[Narreted by"]}</h4>
         <h4>Length: {book.length || book["Length"]}</h4>
```

there are different keys, check in API

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious problem is the data set being returned looks like the keys are inconsistent. You mentioned the first item in the array of books is being returned correctly, but then the following keys `Narreted` and `length` are no longer working. That's because the response object starting in index 1 and beyond (I did not check all of them) have different keys. Specifically the keys in index 1 for example are:

`Narreted by`
`Length`

Try to see why the keys are inconsistent from your API source first and that should get you on the right track. Generally, you want your keys to be spine case or snake case, something other than a space between "Narreted" + "by"

[image]